# Tangent calculation OpenGL

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I am trying to calculate the tangent line (needed for bump mapping) for every vertex in my mesh. The v1, v2 and v3 are the vertices in the triangle and the t1, t2 and t3 are the respective texture coords. From what i understand this should output the tangent line for the three vertices of the triangle.

```
Vec3f va = Vec3f{vertexData[a * 3 + 0], vertexData[a * 3 + 1], vertexData[a * 3 + 2]};
Vec3f vb = Vec3f{vertexData[b * 3 + 0], vertexData[b * 3 + 1], vertexData[b * 3 + 2]};
Vec3f vc = Vec3f{vertexData[c * 3 + 0], vertexData[c * 3 + 1], vertexData[c * 3 + 2]};

Vec2f ta = (Vec2f){texcoordData[a * 2 + 0],texcoordData[a * 2 + 1]};
Vec2f tb = (Vec2f){texcoordData[b * 2 + 0],texcoordData[b * 2 + 1]};
Vec2f tc = (Vec2f){texcoordData[c * 2 + 0],texcoordData[c * 2 + 1]};

Vec3f v1 = subtractVec3f(vb, va);              
Vec3f v2 = subtractVec3f(vc, va);  

Vec2f t1 = subtractVec2f(tb, ta);
Vec2f t2 = subtractVec2f(tc, ta);

float coef = 1/(t1.u * t2.v - t1.v * t2.u);

Vec3f tangent = Vec3fMake((t2.v * v1.x - t1.v * v2.x) * coef,
                          (t2.v * v1.y - t1.v * v2.y) * coef,
                          (t2.v * v1.z - t1.v * v2.z) * coef);
```

My problem is that the `coef` variable is sometimes the `nan (not a number)` value causing the multiplication to be off. My mesh is not super complex, a simple cylinder, but i would like a universal formula to calculate the tangent line to enable bump mapping on all of my meshes.

Answer (score 1):

`coef` becomming a NaN indicates some numerical problem with your input data, like degenerate triangles or texture coordinates. Make sure that the expression `(t1.u * t2.v - t1.v * t2.u)` doesn't (nearly) vanish, i.e. its absolute value is larger than some reasonable threshold value.

A good sanity check is `|vb-va|>0 ^ |vc-va|>0`, `|tb-ta|>0 ^ |tc-ta|>0`, `|normalized(vb-va) . normalized(vc-va)| < 1` and `|normalized(tb-ta) . normalized(tc-ta)| < 1`.